# I want to add timer control in my online examination project

Tags: javascript

i want to create a timer control for my website of online examination

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1000);
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(00, 5, 59, 00);
    function myTimer() {

        if (d.getSeconds() <= 1)
            d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 1, 59, 00);

        var h = d.getHours();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var s = d.getSeconds() - 1;


        if (m == 0 && s == 1)
            window.location.href = "showresults.aspx";
        document.getElementById(" lblCtime.ClientID ").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

        d.setMinutes(m, s);
        //setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    }
</script>

<div style="height:250px;width:400px">
 time left :<Label ID="lblCtime"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"
                ForeColor="Red"></Label>
```

I want to create a timer control for my website of online examination the code is as above i hv written javascript for that and my scrips execurtes but skips the mytimer function tried the below mention code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error here **Wrong id** passed:

```
document.getElementById(" lblCtime.ClientID ").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                         ^                 ^
```

Giving error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Try this code:

```
document.getElementById("lblCtime").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g2R75/)**

Comment: Most welcome. Remember to check console error while running javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1000);
```

With:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
```

You just have to pass a reference to a function in `setInterval`